# One of two mysql queries does not show result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP and I need to select some media from database by id or slug. Can I ask you why this code works fine:

```
index.php?id=1

if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = $id");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row['slug'];
    }
}
```

And this not?

```
index.php?slug=first-post-slug

if( isset( $_GET['slug'] ) ) {
    $slug = $_GET['slug'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE slug = $slug");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
```

The second piece of code does not return anything, and the first piece of code returns proper slug ;/

Comment: I'm guessing that id is an integer and slug is a string

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `mysql_` function in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the variable:

```
$slug = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['slug']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE slug = '". $slug ."'");
```

And also you should cast `id` to **int**:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your effort and pointing me to the right path

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around `$slug`. Otherwise your query looks like in the eyes of the MySQL parser:

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE slug = first-post-slug
```

which is not a valid SQL query.